# MVC Identity Entity Framework model update fails - "Already an object" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

MVC Identity Entity Framework model seems to be broken, preventing model updates. It appears that entity framework models created using IdentityDbContext cannot be updated.

I am using MVC Identity and EF, with a production database as well as a development database. The setup is standard - a project - Models, with the EF configuration, DbSets and EF classes. To create the dev database, I have a simple program listed below. I have used this basic configuration without any issues for a long time. But after moving to MVC Identity, I am now unable to update the dev database by adding new classes to my model. Replacing the reference to IdentityDbContext with the plain DbContext removes the errors. Wonder what I am doing wrong.

Not sure if this is relevant, but many of the entities in the model inherit from a BaseEF class to include common fields.

Models and createDb both use EF 6.0.0.0:

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, 
          Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

I get the following errors:

(1) If I delete the dev database, and run the createDb program, I get the error, "There is already an object named activities in the database".

(2) If I allow the program to delete the database, I get the error that the model backing the database has changed.

I have tried adding and deleting migrations in the Models project without any success.

I am creating the dev database using the following program:

```
namespace AzureV1_CreateTestDB
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      createDb(true);
    }

    public static void createDb(bool deleteDatabase)
    {
      IdentityEFContext dbContext = new IdentityEFContext();

      if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IdentityEFContext"].ConnectionString.Contains("EFUpdatetest1"))
      {
        if (dbContext.Database.Exists())
        {
          if (deleteDatabase)
          {
            // The following line throws this error:
            // System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model backing the 'IdentityEFContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).'

            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction
            , string.Format("ALTER DATABASE {0} SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", dbContext.Database.Connection.Database));

            dbContext.Database.Delete();
          }
        }

        initDBContext(dbContext);
        System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext oContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

        if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IdentityEFContext"].ConnectionString.Contains("EFUpdatetest1"))
        {
          ExecuteSql(oContext, "ALTER DATABASE EFUpdatetest1 SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON");
          ExecuteSql(oContext, "ALTER DATABASE EFUpdatetest1 SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON");
        }

        // insert data
        InsertData(dbContext);

        closeDBContext(dbContext);

        MessageBox.Show("Database successfully created");
      }
    }

    public static void initDBContext(IdentityEFContext dbContext)
    {
      // The following line throws the error:
      // System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There is already an object named 'Activities' in the database.'

      while (((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.Connection.State.ToString() != "Open")
      {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
      }
    }
  }
}
// connectionString in createDb

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IdentityEFContext"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=localhost; Integrated Security=False; Database=EFUpdatetest1; User Id=dbtest; Password=Hello.123" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The EF configuration information is below:

// EntityContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace DataAccess
{
  //public class IdentityEFContext : DbContext /* this works */
  public class IdentityEFContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
  {
    public IdentityEFContext() : base("IdentityEFContext") { }

    static IdentityEFContext()
    {
      Database.SetInitializer<IdentityEFContext>(new IdentityEFInit());
    }

    public static IdentityEFContext Create()
    {
      return new IdentityEFContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ActivityConfig());
      ...
    }
  }

  //public class IdentityEFInit : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<IdentityEFContext>
  public class IdentityEFInit : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<IdentityEFContext>
  {
    protected override void Seed(IdentityEFContext context)
    {
      PerformInitialSetup(context);
      base.Seed(context);
    }

    public void PerformInitialSetup(IdentityEFContext context)
    {
      // initial configuration will go here
    }
  }
}
```

// Entity configurations are as:

```
namespace DataAccess
{
  public class BaseEfConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
  where TEntity : BaseEF
  {
    public BaseEfConfiguration()
    {
      Property(b => b.ServerVersion).IsOptional();
      ...
    }
  }

  public class ActivityConfig : BaseEfConfiguration<Activity>
  {
    public ActivityConfig()
      : base()
    {
      ToTable("Activities");
      Property(a => a.Name).IsRequired();
      HasRequired(a => a.CreatedBy).WithMany(u => u.ActivitiesCreated).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
      ...
    }
  }
}

// connectionstring in app.config
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IdentityEFContext"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=localhost; Integrated Security=False; Database=EFUpdateTest1_Azure; User Id=dbtest; Password=Hello.123" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The User class is:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
  public string Alias { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had not added the migration after making the change to the model and before creating the test database. I did not realize that if the project containing the entity model has migrations enabled, then the project which uses the model to create the database will use the existing migrations information to create the database, not the EntityTypeConfiguration information.

The solution was to first add a migration after updating the model. Then attempt to create the test database as usual.

Hope this is useful to someone.